# Can't open PDF file after decoding String

Tags: android, pdf

I need help with this problem ,i'm recieving base64 string for a PDF file from web service and i'm using this code to convert it again to PDF file in android application

```
 String pdf = "JVBERi0xLjYNJeLjz9MNCjcgMCBvYmoNPDwvTG ... ";
 byte[] pdfAsBytes = Base64.decode(pdf.getBytes(), 0);
    try{

        File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/filename.pdf");
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
        os.write(pdfAsBytes);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

now i'm using Adobe Reader for android to open this file ,but i'm getting this error : The Document Cannt be opened because its not a vaild PDF document .

is the anything i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Try to use Base64.decodeFromString().

Comment: can't resolve method ???!

Comment: Ok. Sorry then i'm mistaken. Compare number of bytes of both files please.

Comment: ok, when i checked the web service the byte was byte[116307] , and when i convert the string to byte in android it's byte[18003]

Comment: Well you are the first one who should comment on these sizes. What do you think is happening?

Comment: I asked for the file lengths which you see in a file explorer. Then you could also tell the length of the base64 string on the sending and receiving side. They should be equal.

Comment: i can see it, but i don't know how to fix it ? i'm sorry i'm new to android programming

Comment: *when i checked the web service the byte was byte[116307] , and when i convert the string to byte in android it's byte[18003]* - how long was the string?